# Push branch to another git

Tags: git

I'm trying to automatically push to another git in my CI/CD. Locally my script works, but the pipeline breaks. The upstream remote has only one branch.

```
git remote add upstream 'https://example.com/foobar.git'
git fetch upstream
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --strategy-option ours upstream/upstream-branch
git push -f upstream upstream-branch
git remote remove upstream
```

As soon as the line with 'push' is called, I get the error in my pipeline:

```
error: src refspec upstream-branch does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://example.com/foobar.git'
```

Comment: Can you try `git push upstream +production:production`? The error message is weird, because you don't push `upstream-branch`, but `production`.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean`git push upstream +HEAD:production`?

Comment: Good point. Which branch do you have checked out currently, what is your HEAD?

Comment: The CI automatically checks out the "production" git

Comment: I've edited my question since there was an erro. "upstream-branch" was "production".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the CI/CD operates with detached head. Origin was as my "my-branch" and detached so I could not push to UPSTREAM "my-branch".